# jQuery append select only works once

Tags: jquery, html

On my page I want to duplicate a `select` element when a user clicks on the `ADD` button. I have this code below, which you can also see on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ma65yuvd/2/).

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var copy = $('#sel').clone().attr('id', '');

$('#add').click(function(){
    $('#test').append(copy);    
});
</script>
```

The code should add an equivalent amount of `select` elements as the user has clicked the `ADD` button. But it only adds one select and seems to be overwriting the initially appended one after the first click of the `ADD` button.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, but offcourse there was a reason why I first cloned it so I could add it later. This is because I use select2(). So I need to the 'raw' select. See this JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ma65yuvd/6/

Answer (score 0):

You want to clone a new one every time they click not just once:

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    var copy = $('#sel').clone().attr('id', '');
    $('#test').append(copy);    
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ma65yuvd/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
// Clones element, creating new element, call it "ElementB"
var copy = $('#sel').clone().attr('id', '');

// Every time you click "add"
$('#add').click(function(){

    // Append "ElementB" to "#test"
    $('#test').append(copy);    
});
```

In other words, you are only creating one DOM element. The first `.append` will move that element to `#test`. The `.append` calls after that will also move it to `#test`, which will result in no net changes.

A simple fix is to call `.clone` each time:

```
var original = $('#sel');

$('#add').click(function(){
    // Now a new element is created for each click!
    var copy = original.clone().attr('id', '');
    $('#test').append(copy);    
});
```

Comment: I replied to my own post. There was a reason why I cloned it in a variable. I need the raw select 'html' to copy multiple times.

Comment: @Timo002 That should be specified in the question itself, because it changes the premise. In that case, instead of cloning it, I would suggest [getting the `outerHtml`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html#answer-10405571) and appending that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the clone inside the click event!

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>

$('#add').click(function(){
    var copy = $('#sel').clone().attr('id', '');
    $('#test').append(copy);    
});
</script>
```

Comment: I replied to my own post. There was a reason why I cloned it in a variable. I need the raw select 'html' to copy multiple times.